# Rxjava message error : Caused by: rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException

Tags: android, rx-java

in my program of android platform, i plan periodic process some logic
, and after  every process of logic , update the view of UI ,
 so i have used the function of Rxjava

```
  Observable.interval
```

but after i do this . i get some error message of Rxjava .
here is the full log .

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add onError handling.
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:57)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException
at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.a(InternalObservableUtils.java:386)
at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(InternalObservableUtils.java:383)
at rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.a(ActionSubscriber.java:44)
at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.b(SafeSubscriber.java:153)
at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.a(SafeSubscriber.java:115)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.a(OperatorObserveOn.java:273)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:216)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)

Caused by: rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.a(OperatorObserveOn.java:160)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.a(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:74)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTimerPeriodically$1.call(OnSubscribeTimerPeriodically.java:52)
at rx.internal.schedulers.SchedulePeriodicHelper$1.call(SchedulePeriodicHelper.java:72)
at rx.internal.schedulers.EventLoopsScheduler$EventLoopWorker$2.call(EventLoopsScheduler.java:189)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

and here it is my code of use Rxjava

```
fun startAnimation(): Unit {

        Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe { start() }

    }
```

the function `start()` is my process of logic

```
  fun start(): Unit = newCircle()



 private fun newCircle(): Unit {
    val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val circle = Circle()
    mCircleList.add(circle)
    invalidate()
    mLastCreateTime = currentTime
}

private inner class Circle {
    var mCreateTime: Long

    init {
        this.mCreateTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }

    val alpha: Int
        get() {
            val percent = (System.currentTimeMillis() - mCreateTime) * 1.3f / mDuration
            val aplpa = ((1.0f - mInterpolator!!.getInterpolation(percent)) * 100).toInt()
            return ((1.0f - mInterpolator!!.getInterpolation(percent)) * 90).toInt()
        }

    val currentRadius: Float
        get() {
            val percent = (System.currentTimeMillis() - mCreateTime) * 1.0f / mDuration
            return mInitialRadius + mInterpolator!!.getInterpolation(percent) * (mMaxRadius - mInitialRadius)
        }
}

fun setInterpolator(interpolator: Interpolator) {
    mInterpolator = interpolator
    if (mInterpolator == null) {
        mInterpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    }
}
```

it my code 
i know nothing about  this issue , so can someone help me understand it ?
thanks !

Comment: Just use `Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe { start() }`

Comment: @akarnokd   `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()`  this code is mean that the Observable process is executed in  IO thread , and in my case ,it is only transmitted Observable  every second,  so will it really be affected ?

Comment: That means that interval is subscribed on the io() thread but because there is no relevant side-effects in subscribing to interval in the first place, subscribeOn is not necessary. Also since interval uses a scheduler to emit items periodically on its own, there is no need for separate observeOn for that but you can specify the mainThread() scheduler directly with interval.

Comment: @akarnokd  sorry came latter and thank your answer , and i will  modify the code  based on your suggestion !!